# Copying data from several excel files into one using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I am confronting the following issues trying to copy RAW DATA from some .csv and .xlsx files into a main excel using python:

```
UserWarning: DrawingML support is incomplete and limited to charts and images only. Shapes and drawings will be lost.
UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
UserWarning: Conditional Formatting extension is not supported and will be removed
UserWarning: Slicer List extension is not supported and will be removed
```

I am currently using python with pandas trying to do this. The issue is:

- the specified sheets for importing RAW DATA to the main excel have no charts, data validation and so on. From A to Z - its just raw data, starting with AA I have some formulas and it shouldn't interfere.
- for the other sheets I have data validation, slicers, graph charts and so on.
  What I am trying to do:
- ignore the sheets that might have problem when opened with pandas/openpyxl/xlsx writer and so on
- copy RAW DATA from .csv/.xlsx files to the main excel file on the specified sheets

I think the problem is that it actually reads the entire workbook and it screws other sheets.
Is there any way that I can do to copy the RAW DATA without screwing the entirely workbook?

Here is the piece of code I tried:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(template1_path, mode="a", engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    df_report1.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, sheet_name=sheet_1, startrow=4)
    df_report2.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, sheet_name=sheet_2, startrow=5)
    df_report3.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, sheet_name=sheet_3, startrow=4)
    df_report4.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, sheet_name=sheet_4, startrow=4)
    df_report5.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, sheet_name=sheet_5, startrow=4)
```

Comment: There's no real way to only partially open, edit and save a workbook unless you want to write the code to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Read data from excel like this first.

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')
```

After making your calculations and functions, just save it to csv if you want to save all to one excel, use

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
```

and save it

```
df.to_csv('path_to_file.csv')
```

OR
save df as xlsx

```
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

If its not working just share some ss please.

Comment: this should be automated; the process is like this: I receive some raw files in mail at a specific hour everyday, I use python to download them and pandas for dataframe in order to rewrite them; after that, the content of them is going to be pasted into the specified sheets; so, in this case, it doesn't help me to do it manual because it would take around 25 minutes and the prio is to do it fast / do other things on another desktop

Comment: Why do you say this is doing it manually? What part of the answer doesn't work for you?

Comment: Volkan edited and shared some code. My comment was for his prev answer. Still, it doesn't work. In the main excel where I want to copy the data, the other sheets have graphs, slicer and so on. Even if I want to modify just the sheets with raw data, it screws the entirely workbook and deletes graphs/slicers and so on. It also loses like 1MB of data, and workbook can't be open - it gives error that the workbook is corrupted and can't be repaired.

Comment: I think you should share some screen shoots with us, because it seems problem is some where else.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed what I was looking for. If anyone interested, here is the solution for my problem:

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False
template = "path"
template2 = "path"
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(template)
sheet1 = workbook.Worksheets('name')
workbook1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(template2)
sheet2 = workbook.Worksheets('name')
# get last row of RAW DATA excel
last_row = sheet2.Range('RANGE').End(win32.constants.xlDown).Row
# copy range RAW DATA excel
source_range = sheet2.Range(f'RANGE:RANGE{last_row}')
source_range.Copy()
# paste range MAIN excel
destination_range = sheet1.Range('RANGE')
destination_range.PasteSpecial(Paste=win32.constants.xlPasteValues)
#if I have big data to copy, skip error when closing the workbook
excel.CutCopyMode = False
workbook1.Close()
workbook.Save()
# move to sheet1 of main excel
workbook.Worksheets(1).Activate()
excel.Application.Quit()
```

I open workbooks with excel.workbooks and simulate Copy/Paste, after I make sure I did my dataframe where I needed to. With this, it doesn't screw the workbook if I have slicer, graph charts, data validation and so on. So, no pandas needed in this case since it doesn't have support for extensions.